# Nice way to keep track of several references between functions in ST monad?

Tags: state, monads, haskell

I'm writing some code (a Metropolis-Hastings MCMC sampler) that will use a random number generator, and modify an array and potentially other structures based on this.

My initial idea was to use the ST monad, so that I could use ST arrays and the mersenne-random-pure64 package, keeping the PureMT generator as part of the state.

However I want to be able to split off some of the work into separate helper functions (e.g to sample a random integer in a given range, to update the array structure, and potentially more complicated things). To do this, I think I would need to pass the references to the PureMT gen and the array to all the functions, which could quickly become very ugly if I need to store more state.

My instinct is to group all of the state into a single data type that I can access anywhere, as I would using the State monad by defining a new datatype, but I don't know if that is possible with the ST monad, or the right way to go about it.

Are there any nice patterns for doing this sort of thing? I want to keep things as general as possible because I will probably need to add extra state and build more monadic code around the existing parts.

I have tried looking for examples of ST monad code but it does not seem to be covered in Real World Haskell, and the haskell wiki examples are very short and simple.

thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> My instinct is to group all of the state into a single data type that I can access anywhere, as I would using the State monad by defining a new datatype, but I don't know if that is possible with the ST monad, or the right way to go about it.
>
> Are there any nice patterns for doing this sort of thing? I want to keep things as general as possible because I will probably need to add extra state and build more monadic code around the existing parts.

The key point to realize here is that it's *completely irrelevant* that you're using `ST`. The `ST` references themselves are just regular values, which you need access to in a variety of places, but you *don't* actually want to change them! The mutability occurs in `ST`, but the `STRef` values and whatnot are basically read-only. They're names *pointing to* the mutable data.

Of course, read-only access to an ambient environment is what the `Reader` monad is for. The ugly passing of references to all the functions is exactly what it's doing for you, but because you're already in `ST`, you can just bolt it on as a monad transformer. As a simple example, you can do something like this:

```
newtype STEnv s e a = STEnv (ReaderT e (ST s) a)
    deriving (Functor, Applicative, Monad)

runEnv :: STEnv s e a -> ST s e -> ST s a
runEnv (STEnv r) e = runReaderT r =<< e

readSTEnv :: (e -> STRef s a) -> STEnv s e a
readSTEnv f = STEnv $ lift . readSTRef . f =<< ask

writeSTEnv :: (e -> STRef s a) -> a -> STEnv s e ()
writeSTEnv f x = STEnv $ lift . flip writeSTRef x . f =<< ask
```

For more generality, you could [abstract over the details of the reference types](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/stateref), and make it into a general "environment with mutable references" monad.

Comment: This sounds like a good idea, I forgot that the references aren't actually changing. Thanks for this! I'm also wondering about possibly using the ST monad from within itself to separate independent stateful computations running in a higher level environment that they don't need to access, with their own hidden local state. Would I need to use the ST monad transformer for this, or can you just use let a = runST $ .... inside the ST monad? If you can (without using the transformer) what would happen if you tried to dereference a ref from the enclosing monad (assuming they would be in scope)?

Comment: @Tom: There is no transformer for `ST`--like `IO`, it's always at the bottom of any stack. Furthermore, any two complete `ST` computations--that is, stuff happening inside a call to `runST`--are completely isolated from each other's state, and any attempt to mix them will give a type error. You can pass opaque values around, just as you could pass `IORef`s around inside `ST`, but you can't *use* them any more than you could use the `IORef`s, either. You can use `runST` just like usual, though; the result of that is a pure value, as always.

Comment: @Tom: Also, if you use a `ReaderT` as in my example, you could probably implement several kinds of bracketing operations without too much trouble--cloning the current environment to run in a separate, inner `ST`, running something in the same `ST` with a different environment, &c.

Comment: thanks, although I think this is a transformer for ST - http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/STMonadTrans/0.2/doc/html/Control-Monad-ST-Trans.html but I don't think it is necessary for what I had in mind.

Comment: @Tom: Well, note that the transformer there messes with `ST`'s internals in a way that breaks if combined with particular other monads, so I'm not sure it *really* counts. But anyway, yes, for what you're doing simple is probably best. A transformer would only be useful if you needed to apply another monad's control structures to the internal state token, which is fraught with peril and not terribly useful anyhow.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the ST monad just like the IO monad, bearing in mind that you only get arrays and refs and no other IO goodies. Just like IO, you can layer a StateT over it if you want to thread some state transparently through your computation.

Comment: Oh I didn't think of that, I think that will solve my problems.